# Changes in golang code are not getting picked after moving to Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, go

I am new to Go lang and have been working on a company internal Go project. I had the golang variables set for a linux user named "ubuntu". But after some time I did the Jenkins setup and I had to change the environment variables for the new Jenkins user. Now when I do a "go get" The changes made to the code are not getting picked.

Before Jenkins setup environment variables:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin # add for go installation
export GOPATH=$HOME/apps # add go work directory
export GOBIN=$HOME/apps/bin # add go bin work directory
export GIN_MODE=release # enable it for production mode
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

After Jenkins setup:

```
export GOPATH=/var/lib/jenkins/apps
export GOBIN=/var/lib/jenkins/apps/bin
export GOROOT=/var/lib/jenkins/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.golang.GolangInstallation/Go_1.6
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH
```

What is the problem is here?